# disable windowAnimations when pressing Home button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

So for one of my `Dialog`s I'm implementing a sliding animation. It works well for enter and exit. However, when the user presses the Home button, and the app is backgrounded, the `windowExitAnimation` still plays, and when going back to app, the `windowEnterAnimation` also plays. Is there a way to only play these animations when showing/dismissing the dialog and not when using the Home button?

This is the theme for my xml

```
<style name="MyDialogAnimationTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyDialogAnimationTheme.Window</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialogAnimationTheme.Window" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>
```

and in code i am setting the theme via overriding `getTheme()` for the `DialogFragment`

```
@Override
public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.MyDialogAnimationTheme;
}
```

i've also tried setting the `windowAnimation` like so:

```
myDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.MyDialogAnimationTheme_Window;
```

but same problem, the animation plays fine but also plays for Home button backgrounding the app.

Comment: Same problem for me